# iOS, set properties on embedded views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a control panel style app which, on tap of a help icon, provides an overlay layer equal to the self.view frame (a glass layer) where text & direction arrows provide insight into the apps use.

In the root `UIViewController` i have a `UIContainer` embedded with a `UITableViewController`. I'm modal styling, or greying out various elements on the view controller to attracted the user's attention to the UI element in question.

In order to grey out (change the background colour) of the table, would i need to setup a delegate method between the root view controller & the embedded uitableview controller? or is there a simpler way to achieve the described effect?

Answer (score 0):

If you've done this correctly, the child view controller is the parent view controller's `childViewControllers[0]`. So there should be no problem communicating between one view controller and the other.